# Naming audio plug-ins using JUCE framework

Tags: plugins, signal-processing, audio-recording, juce

I've been working on developing some audio plugins recently using the JUCE framework. I'm having an issue regarding naming the plugin. I've created separate projects for entirely different plugins. However when I load the plugin by starting Logic Pro X, I seem to only get the most recent plugin that I built, however, the plugin is always title as the very first plugin that I made. That is to say, It seems that when I make a new plugin, it takes on the name of my previous plugin and replaces it.

I've tried renaming the Plugin Code, but the AU validation tool recognizes the plugin as having the Plugin Code of the previous plugin.

Has anyone come across this problem or have any suggesting as to what might be causing it?

Additionally, I was using the WDL framework before using JUCE and had the same problem. This of course makes me think that the problem is not specific to JUCE or WDL.

Any input is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: There's an audiounit cache you might try clearing: http://www.arturia.com/faq/utilization/how-do-i-clear-my-audio-unit-cache

Answer (score 0):

Open the Introjucer with one of your projects and select the "Config" tab in the left panel. Then select your project at the top of the tree view.

In the right panel, you should see 2 fields called "Plugin Manufacturer Code" and "Plugin Code".

Your other project should have the same Plugin Manufacturer code, but a different Plugin Code to uniquely identify each plugin.